# Prove the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(z - \lambda_1)\cdots(z - \lambda_n)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space and $T:V\to V$. Suppose that with respect to some basis of $V$ the matrix of $T$ is upper triangular, with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ on the diagonal of this matrix. Prove the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(z - \lambda_1)\cdots(z - \lambda_n)$.

I think I understand how to prove this statement using the determinant, but I am asked to prove it in a different way (not using the determinant) and I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: What is your definition of characteristic polynomial?

Comment: As the characteristic polynomial is defined in terms of the determinant, this might be difficult.

Comment: You might be able to use Cayley Hamilton here, but that seems like overkill

Comment: Sorry, but, what have you already done? and what would be "using the determinant"? you mean, strictly computing $P_{T}(\lambda) = det(\lambda\mathbb{I} - T)$ where $T$ is the triangular matrix of the linear transformation?

Comment: @lhf polynomial $(z - \lambda_1)^{d_1}\cdots(z - \lambda_m)^{d_m}$ with $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ distinct eigenvalues and $d_1,\ldots,d_m$ multiplicities

Comment: @NicoF. Yes, I know how to prove it using the fact that the characteristic polynomial equals $det(zI - T)$ for $T:V\to V$, but I am supposed to prove it in some other way, without the determinant

Answer (score 2):

Not using determinants directly... it should not be too hard to convince yourself that the kernel of $T - \lambda I$ is nontrivial whenever the value of $\lambda$ is the same as a diagonal element of $T$. Since $T$ has full rank, this is precisely what it means for $\lambda$ to be an eigenvalue of $T$ and the result follows.